# Android GridView Custom Adapter only ever displays a single row

Tags: android, listadapter

I am working on a ListView with items that can expand to show a GridView. The ListView and adapter work fine, and the GridView expands fine when added, but I cannot get it to display more than a single row in the grid. There is only ever a single column displayed, no matter the length I set the column to, and it's clear that the issue isn't that the view is just too small (I have tried making it have an absurdly large height). I've browsed other questions here but this doesn't seem to be a common problem. What am I doing wrong?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scorecardGridView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:columnWidth="25dp"
android:numColumns="18"
android:isScrollContainer="false"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center" />
```

GridAdapter getView() code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("position",String.valueOf(position));
    TextView textView;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(25, 25));
    } else {
        textView = (TextView) convertView;
    }
    if (position < 18)
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
    else {
        position -= 18;
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        if (scores[position] > 0) {
            textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.red));
            textView.setText("+" + String.valueOf(scores[position]));
        } else {
            if (scores[position] < 0)
                textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.blue));
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(scores[position]));
        }
    }
    return textView;
}
```

I am using this to show a two row, 18 column golf scorecard. No matter what I do, only the first row shows. If I change the numColumns attribute, that new number of columns shows, but always just one row. You can see I tried Logging the positions for which getView() is being called, and it is revealing that it is only being called for the first row.

Let me know if you want to see any other code, thanks.

Comment: Are you putting your gridview inside a scrollview?